# Create a list of time in M:S, each value must be repeated 3 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a list of time in M:S, but each value must be repeated 3 times.[0:00,0:00,0:00,0:01,0:01,0:01,0:02...]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. 
It's for solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. 
Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. 
See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use strings for the times in the list because I don't know which data type you hope to use for them. I'll also use a 24 hour clock.
Hope this helps:

```
[f"{m//3}:{s//3:02d}" for m in range(60*3) for s in range(60*3)]
```

This will only work if you are using python 3.6 or above, because that's when f-strings were added. If you're using a version below 3.6, you can use .format() instead, replacing every instance of `f'{x}...{y:02d}'` in the code with `'{}...{:02d}'.format(x, y)`.

*Edit: Modifications of int(x/3) to x//3 and replacement of secs logic to :02d based on @MadPhysict's recommendation.*

Comment: Use `//` instead of `int`

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're right, good advice. I completely forgot that operator existed

Comment: The whole logic for `secs` should be removed. Print it as `'{m//3:02d}:{s//3:02d}'`

Comment: @aexxy glad to have helped

Comment: @MadPhysicist that is also an improvement I missed out on. _sweats nervously._ I'm very much a beginner to python myself and never learnt about that string formating technique (because I'm pretty much self taught). I've done classes in school but only extreme basics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys! Can I ask u one more question. I need to make this list from 0:00 to 9:08. So, I think I should use some another method to do it.

Comment: No, you don't need a different method. All you have to do is change `m in range(24*3)` to `m in range(9*3)` and put a `+ [f"{9}:{s//3:02d}" for s in range(8*3)]` at the end, like so `[f"{m//3}:{s//3:02d}" for m in range(9*3) for s in range(60*3)] + [f"{9}:{s//3:02d}" for s in range(8*3)]`